# Angular ng-version not updating

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I create a new Angular app using `dotnet new angular` which currently specifies Angular `4.2.5` in the package.json. I run the app and view source and `ng-version` is `4.2.5` which is correct.

I then specify Angular to use `4.4.6` in the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6"
```

I completely remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.  After install, I check `.\node_modules\@angular\common\package.json` and it shows a `4.4.6` version. However, when I run the app, `ng-version` still shows `4.2.5`. Why does it still show `4.2.5`? How do I fix this?

Comment: Updating the package doesn't necessarily update your app build. Did you run your build script?

Comment: @isherwood I ran `dotnet build` which succeeds and then `dotnet run`.

Comment: @isherwood disregard. Appears to be a caching issues. If I do a `ctrl+F5` the correct version shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to have been a caching issue. Doing a Ctrl+F5 made the correct version appear.